# I have 4 Ethernet RJ45 ports which were limited to 200KB per second. How to use all 4 ports to speed up my network connection?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have 4 Ethernet RJ45 ports under my desk. The speed of those ports were limited to 200KB per second. Is there a way to use all 4 ports to speed up my network connection? What I want is 200KB X 4 = 800KB per second.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the ports are limited? Standard ethernet is 10Mbps (That's about 1.25Megabytes/second), and the norm now is 100Mbs (12.5Megabytes/second)

Comment: I know it was limited on the switch. I was told by the network guys in our company.

Comment: Your easiest solution is to ask the network people to remove the limits. If you try and combine 4 ports they will need to be involved.

Comment: No that's not what I want. What I want is how to use these 4 ports by myself to speed up network access. Or is it possible?

Comment: Op, this is likely not possible, and even if it were, many types of data flows will be limited to a single line. if you have 4 nics in the workstation, and the nics and switch support link-aggregation (802.1ax) and you can configure the switch, then you may be able to implement what you are going for, but it will not provide as much advantage as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Use 4 lan cards, and the **Dispatch** application.
(Or two cards with two ports. Whatever works, you need 4 ports/interfaces.)

The application itself:
http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/

This should work.